# Modify existing MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a MapKit view with a large number of default `MKAnnotationView` pins.  I would like to modify an existing pin (i.e. one that's been on the view for a while, not during initial appearance).  When the underlying data for a location changes I'd like to change its subtitle, and give it a small animation (jiggle or similar).

While I see my `MKAnnotationView`'s, they do not appear to have `superview`'s.  For example:

```
for (MKAnnotationView *annotationView in self.mapView.annotations) {
    if (annotationView.superview) {
        NSLog(@"Hooray!");
    }
}
```

While I have many annotations (I see them, plus I've seen them in the debugger here), none have a superView.

Is this doable?  Or will I need to implement a custom view for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mapView.annotations` is an array of annotations, not of annotation views. I'm a little surprised that it didn't crash when you tried calling the `superview` method on the annotation.

To get the annotation view, it is

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (id)[mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
if (annotationView) {
    // annotation view for this annotation is available
}
```

I'm unclear why you need the `superview` for the annotation view, though. Personally, I'd be hesitant to mess around in the map view's internal view hierarchy.

If I wanted to animate the changing of the color, I might do something like:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *visibleAnnotationView = (id)[mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
if (visibleAnnotationView) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:visibleAnnotationView duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
        visibleAnnotationView.pinTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Obviously, do whatever animation you want, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Note, though, that the situation is actually a little more complicated than this, because if the user pans the annotation view off screen and then back on, your `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` would have to know what type of annotation view to return. So you'd probably end up wanting to have a custom `MKAnnotation` subclass with whatever state information you need so that `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` could act accordingly.

Comment: It did not crash because he called `superview` on the MKAnnotationsViews, which are a subclass of UIView.

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you @Rob.  Not sure how I missed that mapView.annotations weren't annotationViews, although it makes perfect sense.  I wish it had crashed, would have saved me some time!  viewForAnnotation gives me the view, and away we go. I didn't need the superView; that was just a test to confirm my suspicion that I wasn't getting the same view as was on screen (since it wasn't reacting the way I'd anticipate.)  Now I know why.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Ares "he called superview on the MKAnnotationsViews" ... No, that's not true. He iterated through `mapView.annotations` (which is an array of annotations, not annotation views), happening to cast them to a type of `MKAnnotationView`. But casting an object to a different class does not magically change the object's actual, underlying class. They're still annotations. He either (a) incorrectly defined his annotation class such that it responded to `superview` (e.g. wrong base class); or (b) `mapView` was `nil`; or (c) the `mapView` didn't have any annotations (notice, no `else` clause).